# Overflowing issue when allocating tree nodes

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I'm currently working on a problem that requires me to generate an n-ary tree based on given vertex pairs, which are read in from an input file. This is my current Node class:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private int idx;
    private int data;
    private Node<T> parent;
    private List<Node<T>> children;

    // Template for new nodes
    public Node() {
        this.idx = 1;
        this.data = 0;
        this.parent = null;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    public void insertNode(Node<T> currNode, int leftIdx, int rightIdx) {
        if (currNode.idx == leftIdx) {
            Node<T> childNode = new Node<T>();
            childNode.idx = rightIdx;
            childNode.parent = currNode;
            currNode.children.add(childNode);            
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < currNode.children.size(); i++) {
            Node<T> tempNode = currNode.children.get(i);
            if (tempNode.idx == leftIdx ) {
                Node<T> childNode = new Node<T>();
                childNode.idx = rightIdx;
                childNode.parent = tempNode;
                tempNode.children.add(childNode);            
                return;
            }
        }

        Node<T> upCurrNode = currNode.children.get(currNode.children.size() - 1);
        upCurrNode.insertNode(upCurrNode, leftIdx, rightIdx);
        return;
    }          
}
```

As you can see, my insertNode method is being called recursively, in order to populate the whole tree with all its nodes, with no data. There are additional methods for adding values to these nodes as well, but the input file is split into two parts - creating nodes first, then performing queries that update the data inside each node later (I have no control over this).

I ran this with two input files, one with around one hundred nodes within the tree, the other is two orders of magnitude larger. The smaller tree works just fine, but I got the following error upon testing it with the larger tree, which occurs after the ~2050th recursive call:

```
Node: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
        at node.Node.insertNode(Node.java:38)
        at node.Node.insertNode(Node.java:44)
        at node.Node.insertNode(Node.java:44)
        at node.Node.insertNode(Node.java:44)
        at node.Node.insertNode(Node.java:44)
        at node.Node.insertNode(Node.java:44)...
        (repeats for a couple thousand lines)
```

Line 38 is `System.out.format("Node: %d Parent: %d\n", childNode.idx, childNode.parent.idx);` while line 34 is the recursive `insertNode` call: `upCurrNode.insertNode(upCurrNode, leftIdx, rightIdx);`.

My best guess on this issue is that the program overflows the default memory allocation for the JVM, based on the thrown StackOverflowError exception. Understandably, I can also see that my memory overhead for each node is quite high: 4 bytes for the `idx` field, another 4 for `data`, another 4 for reference to `parent` node, and 40 bytes + whatever amount the ArrayList itself needs for overhead for creating a default one for `children`. Assuming that the total memory required per each node is ~70KB, the bigger tree's total size will be around 700MB, which is beyond ridiculous for such a simple program (I was wrong, by the way; see my comment below).

So, my question now is: is my insertNode method that inefficient? Is there a way to optimize it such that it can handle a large amount of data, without requiring the person running the program to pass a special flag that allows increased memory usage? Thank you

Edit: Here's a code snippet on how the tree was first generated:

```
Node<Integer> tree = new Node<Integer>();  
String line = null; // line reader
// temp variables for processing nodes during tree generation
int leftNodeIdx, rightNodeIdx; 
// String array for processing node indexes
String[] twoNodesIdx;
// first line is the number of nodes    
int numN = Integer.parseInt( bufferedReader.readLine() ); 
// Populate the tree with child nodes as specified in the input_file 
for (int i = 0; i < (numN - 1); i++) {
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    twoNodesIdx = line.split("\\s");
    leftNodeIdx = Integer.parseInt(twoNodesIdx[0]);
    rightNodeIdx = Integer.parseInt(twoNodesIdx[1]);
    tree.insertNode(tree, leftNodeIdx, rightNodeIdx);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your main method so I can see how insertNode() is set up and called?

Comment: No update for `leftIndex`

Comment: @nhouser9: check my edit.

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen: Can you be a little more specific? I'm not sure which `leftIdx` you meant.

Also, I was way off on my memory calculation. Fortunately, I changed my stack size to 2MB with `-Xss2m`, and now the program can handle the bigger input file just fine, so I think I'll probably leave it at that. I'm still open to suggestions on optimizations, however. I'd love to be able to run this using the JVM's default stack size.

Comment: @RChan what is the use of leftIdx and rightIdx?

Comment: @SumeetSingh They're given vertex pairs that tell which node is connected to which. The second half of this problem is to process some queries on this tree (ie. updating the data in each node), which requires me to reconstruct a tree based on these vertex pairs data first.